# meaning of "[subject] [negated verb], as [clause]"

Tags: grammar

Consider the following statement:

> I will not carry an umbrella tomorrow, as I do on rainy days.

It might seem clear to us that the meaning is that the speaker intends not to carry an umbrella, though   carrying an umbrella is usual on rainy days.

The reason this meaning is clear may owe in part to our understanding of the ontological relationship between an expectation of rain and carrying an umbrella.
Suppose such understanding were unavailable to us.

For example, imagine a sentence of the following form:

> I will not carry an *umburgle* tomorrow, as I do on *strainy* days.

Suppose the meanings of the words *umburgle* and *strainy* are understood by others, but not by us, and we are to decide between the following meanings:

1. The speaker intends not to carry an *umburgle*, **though** carrying one is **usual** of *strainy* days.
2. The speaker intends not to carry an *umburgle*, **because** carrying one is **unusual** on *strainy* days.

Does English grammar (i.e. syntax) give any single interpretation of this sentence, with respect to the above distinction, or is it essentially ambiguous?

Comment: The salient interpretation is that you normally carry an umbrella on rainy days, but you won't tomorrow, where "as" is competition with "like". It's a comparative construction where the complement of "do" is obligatorily omitted. In full, it would be "I will not carry an umbrella tomorrow, as I do carry an umbrella on rainy days". Nothing at all wrong with it all.

Comment: You have indeed found a misinterpretation possible in an imaginary, bizarre world. But it's more human nature than English to understand that umbrellas are for rainy days, not for avoiding on rainy days.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: The purpose the question is to understand abstractly the sentence structure, in case it might sometime be applied to words with not such an obvious relationship.

Comment: @epl Your recent edit to the question now causes me to have no understanding at all of what you're asking. I've deleted my answer, since it's obviously not addressing what you're trying to ask. Why is any word spelled the way it is, and have the meaning it does? Because we've made it so through use. But I can't see how the added second part of the question has anything to do with the first part …

Comment: @JasonBassford: In the second part we cannot use our understanding of the meanings of the words to infer whether the speaker does or does not normally carry the item on specific days (as we may do with *umbrella* and *rain*). The question is which interpretations come forth from the grammar alone?

Comment: I reworked the text. I may not have pinpointed the cause of misunderstanding, but I tried.

Comment: @BillJ: Are you indicating that the syntax excludes the interpretation that "do" refers to "not carry" rather  "carry"? If so, an explanation of this effect would address the question.